# Error in update of python-minimal

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

When I run an update on Ubuntu 18.04, it shows that the packages below are upgradable. But when I run `sudo apt upgrade` it doesn't upgrade it. It upgrades all other packages if there are any but not the 5 packages below. I tried to upgrade individually but it seems there's a break in the system.

```
libpython-dev/bionic 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.15~rc1-1]
libpython-stdlib/bionic 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.15~rc1-1]
python/bionic 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.15~rc1-1]
python-dev/bionic 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.15~rc1-1]
python-minimal/bionic 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.15~rc1-1]
```

Is there any way that I can upgrade these packages? When I run `sudo apt upgrade libpython-dev` for example, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev (>= 2.7.15-1~) but 2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2-dev (= 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b) but it is not going to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Please help.

When I run `dpkg -l | grep oibaf`, I get

```
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                       2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-common                              2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 all          Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- common files
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                        2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                      2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-radeon1:amd64                       2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 amd64        Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm2:amd64                              2.4.99+git1908090630.149225~oibaf~b                 amd64        Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                         19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                         19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgbm1:amd64                              19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        generic buffer management API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                      19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libllvm9:amd64                             1:9~+rc1-1~exp1~oibaf~b                             amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libwayland-client0:amd64                   1.16.0-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - client library
ii  libwayland-cursor0:amd64                   1.16.0-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - cursor library
ii  libwayland-egl1:amd64                      1.16.0-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - EGL library
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64                 19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libwayland-server0:amd64                   1.16.0-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - server library
ii  libxatracker2:amd64                        19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        X acceleration library -- runtime
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                      19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64                   19.2~git1908100730.9c5975~oibaf~b                   amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  19.0.1+git1908071930.e6fce5~oibaf~b                 amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                     1:19.0.1+git1907231930.c7ed12~oibaf~b               amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git1907241930.6f4972~oibaf~b             amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                 1:1.0.16+git1906080730.ec2b45~oibaf~b               amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                  1:19.0.1+git1907231930.c7ed12~oibaf~b               amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
```

`grep -ir oibaf /etc/apt --include="*.list"` gives me

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-bionic.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic main
```

Lastly, `apt-cache policy libpython-dev` results to

```
libpython-dev:
  Installed: 2.7.15~rc1-1
  Candidate: 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b
  Version table:
     2.7.15-3~oibaf~b 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.7.15~rc1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Oibaf : Not the official Ubuntu packages. ... You can check the "oibaf ppa" entries ... https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+ppa-packages ... : I cannot find any python among the 479 listed packages. ... May be this private supplier isn't offering python packages anymore ?

Comment: Please add complete output of `dpkg -l | grep oibaf`, `grep -ir oibaf /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`, `apt-cache policy libpython-dev` to the question.

Comment: @karel The steps in the duplicate didn't work. Nothing happened.

Comment: @N0rbert, already updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the most clear result I'll recommend to purge the [problematic PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers?field.series_filter=bionic) and use packages from official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and then install remaining updates with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, @N0rbert. Seems like it worked.

Answer (score -1):

you have 2 options i guess

**option 1**

you use apt-get for fix this

`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

**option 2**

using dpkg

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get update`

and finally :
`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

hope it helps

Comment: It didn't work. I tried it but nothing happened. The upgradable packages are still there.